# How to replace my gas hedge trimmer rope starter

Tags: tools, tool-maintenance

The rope starter for my Craftsman Gas Hedge Trimmer disconnected from the engine while pulling to start.
Please explain how to reattach this rope starter. I am a DIY individual. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

It is hard to give really detailed advice on how to fix the pull rope. However generally speaking the shroud over the rope recoil winder assembly needs to be removed. Then it is possible to get at the rope re-winder assembly to reattach the rope. Usually the rope is knotted at the end and slips into a notch or retainer bracket on the spool of the rewinder. Note that the rewinder needs to have a small amount of tension placed on the rope when it is in the fully rolled up position. This tension keeps the rope from hanging loose and coming part way out when the machine is in use. Also be careful to not put too much tension on the fully rolled up rope as then you may not be able to pull the rope all the way out when trying to start the engine.

The re-winder works a lot like a tape measure.

Comment: +1 I'd also mention that, while you've got it open, you might as well *replace* the rope if it has any wear at all. I find this procedure somewhat tedious, so it's worth putting a new rope on while you're doing the job anyway.

Answer (score 4):

a couple tips:  don't lose those nuts; remember the direction the rope is wound; and finally your last step should be making a good stopper knot that won't pull through or come undone at ﻿the handle. Make sure there is a little tension on ﻿the rope where you make ﻿the knot.